# Stop timer on hover and continue from the same place

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with Timeout. So, I have a 4 second countdown timer which when reset becomes 4 seconds again. However, if I move the mouse over the block, my timer stops. When I remove the mouse from the block - the timer becomes 4 seconds again and starts to decrease. It was correct work. However, now I'm trying to implement another functionality - I would like that when I remove the mouse from the block, the timer does not become 4 seconds, but continues from the same place. That is, 2 seconds have passed, and when I remove the mouse, there should be 2 seconds left, not 4.

Here is my code with functions and my block.

```
   const autoplayInterval = 4000; // ms
   const [remainingTimer, setRemainingTimer] = useState(0);
   const [timerStart, setTimerStart] = useState(Date.now());
   const [mouseEntered, setMouseEntered] = useState(false);

   setTimeout(() => {
        if (mouseEntered) return
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const diff = currentTime - timerStart;
        setRemainingTimer(autoplayInterval - diff);
    }, 16);

    const mouseEnterHandler = () => {
        setRemainingTimer(autoplayInterval)
        setMouseEntered(true);
    }

    const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
        setTimerStart(Date.now());
        setMouseEntered(false)
    }

    return (
        <div onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler} onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveHandler}></div>
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this should do the work:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react'

const Timer = () => {
  const [remainingTimer, setRemainingTimer] = useState(4000);
  const [mouseEntered, setMouseEntered] = useState(false);
  let timer = useRef(null)

  timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if (mouseEntered) return
      setRemainingTimer(remainingTimer - 16);
  }, 16);


  const mouseEnterHandler = () => {
      setMouseEntered(true);
  }

  const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
      setMouseEntered(false)
  }

  if (remainingTimer < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer.current)
    return <div>finished</div>
  }

  return (
      <div 
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler} 
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveHandler} 
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
      >
        remaining {remainingTimer}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Timer
```